# Threaded thumbnail-loading for imageview in a table cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, imageview, nsthread

I'm looking for suggestions on how to make an efficient thumbnail-loader for navigation-lists in the form of tables. I can start a thread and download and cache the thumbnails, but I'm unsure on how to update a table cell with the image (a cell either visible or outside the view).

I think the app Blocket does what I'm after, if I remember correctly.

I'd like to set a placeholder image, and as the thread loads each image, it updates the cells. The placeholder could be an animated activity indicator (spinner), if possible.

Are there any terse example-code out there, or can you give suggestions on how to communicate the update to the cell and force it to display the image immediately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Made the nicest threaded thumbnail loading I've seen yet on iPhone :D The hardest part was cancelling a thread when navigating away from its table. An NSThread loading images and performSelectorOnMainThread waitUntilDone:YES for when updating the cell.imageView, passing objects (cell, tableView, indexPath etc) in an array to bypass the limitation of passing only one object in withObject. Looks royale with a quick fade-in of each image as they load :)

Comment: Cheesy mark-your-own-answer since I basically had to solve how to do it myself and this answer has a few specifics that may help others.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem.

I guess at some level you'll need to replace the existing cells in the table view via the `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:withRowAnimation:` [UITableView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method, so I suspect you'll need to keep a lookup of cell contents -> indexPaths so you know which cells to update when the relevant asset becomes available.

However, you'll need to avoid breaking the existing cell re-use system. (i.e.: there's no value in pre-creating all of the cells in advance.) As such, much of this work should be done within the - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method, I suspect.

That said, hopefully you'll get a better response than these somewhat vague ramblings. :-)

Comment: Made me think of something. Possibly it could suffice with a [mytable reloadData] when loading-thread is done. This will only refresh the visible cells, but when the view is scrolled cellForRow... will be called and the replaced images are used in the cell imageview.